# How do I take off these plastic buttons that are attaching the shroud to my car?

Tags: plastic, clips

I need to get a closer look at my headlight assembly, but there is a plastic shroud/guard covering it. It's attached with little plastic buttons.

[image: top view]

[image: bottom view]

Comment: Do I just squeeze the bottom with pliers and pull it out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put a screwdriver in the slot on the side and gently raise up the center section. You may need to work it from both sides. Once the center section is raised, it should look something like this:

[image: Image from Amazon.com]

Once the center section is raised, grab it from the base (or put your screwdriver under the base) and wiggle it free.

Comment: In addition to using a flathead screwdriver, there are various styles of trim removal tools available that I've found to be gentler with the sometimes brittle plastic. My preferred style for these types of clips is a tool like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Lisle-35260-Plastic-Fastener-Remover/dp/B0002SRCMO).

Comment: And whenever you need to remove those kinds of clips, know that some of the clips *will* break. They're just not made for re-use but for quick and easy *installation* (in the factory). You may want to get a bunch of them as replacements, either cheap generic ones from a set or the one or two types you expect to encounter from the dealership. If you have like 10 spares of each ready, you may find the repair to go much easier because you don't worry and spend 10 minutes to remove a single clip without breaking it, or worse, damage the part held by the clip while trying to keep the clip intact.